# Google Static Maps API - Error while encoding polyline

Tags: google-maps

I'm using google maps' [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html) to plot locations on a map. When I try to plot 31.63089000, 74.87155200, I get an error "Invalid location entered. Must be in range of -90 to 90".

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you're using?

Comment: I'm entering the following values in the link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html

Center map at: 31.63089000, 74.87155200
Latitude: 31.63089000
Longitude: 74.87155200
Display Level: 3

When I click on the Add Location button, I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the form code here:

```
var lat = document.getElementById('txtLatitude').value;
  var pLat = parseFloat(lat);

  if (pLat.toString() != lat) {
    alert('Invalid latitude entered. Must be in range of -90 to 90');
    return;
  }
```

It works for me if I truncate your numbers to 31.63089 and 74.871552.  The problem in that javascript is that parseFloat is truncating the trailing zeroes off the end.  So it converts 31.63089000 to 31.63089.  And then 31.63089 is != what was entered in the form, 31.63089000, hence the error.  Suggest you file this as a bug with whoever's responsible.

Comment: Even I tried with truncating the number, and it worked. Considering your comment as the answer I'm closing the question. Thanks for the help.